# Identify the audio system in 2007 BMW E92

Tags: bmw, audio

Looking to buy an E92 335d. I’ve seen one for sale and and trying to understand the audio system fitted. This is the only picture I have of the head unit etc:

[image]

I’m completely unfamiliar with BMW audio system, except I think there are 3 levels of amp/speaker combinations and various head units.

The seller says it’s the basic system, but it’s obviously iDrive, it had CD and DVD(?) slots and it that a dashboard centre speaker visible, which I understood was only found on the top speaker/amp combination?

Thanks for any help identifying it.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair. From what I've seen online, it looks as though you are right about the CD and DVD slots (little DVD insignia is blocked by the steering wheel). What you are seeing up top appears to be some sort of vent and not a sound port, though. Looks like iDrive due to the center screen.

Comment: Thanks - a bit of investigating reveals that the grills on the dash are there even if there is no speaker. I assumed that the 'professional' DVD/iDrive system would have the good audio, but apparently the head unit fitted bears no relationship to the speaker/amp package.

Comment: Does BMW do the same as Ford - go on the website : enter your VIN and it will give the original build specification (the Ford ETIS system). That may help answer your question.

Comment: E92 M3 is the best M3!

Comment: @Supertecnoboff I know,  but I’m going to be doing a 110m M25 commute each day, so need some fuel economy!

Comment: @SteveIves ah right I see. Then again the M25 is mostly comprised of heavy traffic. Just use the eco start/stop mode to save fuel. Plus the V8 sound is heavenly when you have the room to put your foot down :)

Comment: @Supertecnoboff Yep - looking for start/stop, an auto (would always go for a manual - not an option on the 335, I know - but fancy the paddles and an auto is good in traffic) and active cruise. I'm hoping to travel before the main rush hour, but I know that won't always pan out.

Comment: @Supertecnoboff E90 M3 > E92 M3, but I'm a super sedan guy c:

Answer (score 1):

Ok - that’s the Professional navigation system (bigger screen, more features and maybe a hard drive?). But that says noth8ng about the amp and speakers. If I could see the corners of the front windows, a lack of triangular tweeters would indicate the basic speaker system.

However BMW does/did an official Alpine amp & speaker package consisting of the tweeters, new mid range drivers for the front doors and a power amp for the boot for about £380 and a few hours of install time.

Still not sure about Bluetooth or USB audio connectivity though.